# How to create an object from unknown data that will be one of several possible types?

Tags: typescript

I am getting data from a server.

```
const response = await request() as RecordingGetChannelData
```

This data can be one of three types.

```
export type RecordingGetChannelData = (
    RecordingGetChannelDataAnalogValues | 
    RecordingGetChannelDataGpiAndRxChannels | 
    RecordingGetChannelDataValueObject
);
export type RecordingGetChannelDataAnalogValues = {
    data_type: 'analog';
    timestamp: number;
    interval: number;
    values: number[];
    value: string;
};
export type RecordingGetChannelDataGpiAndRxChannels = {
    data_type: 'log';
    values: number[];
    value: string;
};
export type RecordingGetChannelDataValueObject = {
    timestamp: number;
    value: string;
};
```

From this `response` I want to create an object `channelData` that is of one of three types

```
export type ChannelData = (
    ChannelDataAnalogValues | 
    ChannelDataGpiAndRxChannels | 
    ChannelDataValueObject
);
export type ChannelDataAnalogValues = {
    data_type: 'analog';
    timestamp: number;
    interval: number;
    values: number[];
    value: string;
};
export type ChannelDataGpiAndRxChannels = {
    data_type: 'log';
    values: number[];
    value: string;
};
export type ChannelDataValueObject = {
    timestamp: number;
    value: string;
};
```

How can I do this?

This is my best attempt, but it does not work:

```
let channelData = {};
if (response['data_type']) channelData.dataType = response['data_type'];
if (response['timestamp']) channelData.timestamp = response['timestamp'];
if (response['interval']) channelData.interval = response['interval'];
if (response['values']) channelData.values = response['values'];
if (response['value']) channelData.value = response['value'];
```

PS: I still don't quite understand when I should uses types vs interfaces, so if interfaces are more suitable for this kind of task I have nothing against using that instead.

Comment: If your `RecordingGetChannelData` and `ChannelData` types are identical then why are you creating `ChannelData` objects? Can't you just use the result object directly?

More globally, I think you may be trying to use Typescript in the wrong way. Remember types are stripped away at compile-time and cannot be used at runtime...

If you cannot change the response (i.e. separate out different objects into endpoints), then I would just use a single interface with optional parameters.

Comment: We can't assume that they are the same. In the case above a property os called 'data_type' on RecordingGetChannelData and 'dataType' on ChannelData.